# Chrome Browser Addon displaying history as screenshots?

Tags: chrome, history, web-browser

Is there a Chrome extension which shows the history as a list of images by automated site screenshots? 
I did not find anything.
thx

Comment: It should show a history of the site or your browser history?

Comment: It should show the browser history with screenshot images, not only favicons.
The go-back-history of tabs maybe also :)